# Flutter WebRTC camera doesn't show up

Tags: flutter, webrtc, simplewebrtc, webrtc-android, openwebrtc

I'm working on WebRTC for video calling in Flutter. Everything is working like charm, but when I run the app it does not show the camera both local camera and remote (Camera Permission is given), but if I hot reload the app the camera shows.

This is my code.

[image]

Here is my UI.

```
Expanded(
    child: Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
      child: Row(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
        children: [
          Expanded(child: RTCVideoView(_localRenderer, mirror: true)),
          Expanded(child: RTCVideoView(_remoteRenderer)),
        ],
      ),
    ),
),`
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try adding a `setState` after calling the `getUserMedia()` function. I'll show you my example.

```
ElevatedButton(
            onPressed: () async {
              await signaling.openUserMedia(_localRenderer, _remoteRenderer);
              setState(() {});
              print("Open Camera");
            },
            child: const Text("Open camera & microphone"),
          ),
```