# flutter_webrtc no local webcam video on emulator/mobile

Tags: android, flutter, dart, video, webrtc

I'm trying to get the flutter_webrtc package running. As a first step I've tried to show the local webcam video in a RTCVideoView. This works fine on a browser, but neither on the Android emulator nor on a real device I can see the video. All permissions (according to the docs) are in place. And I'm getting asked on the emulator/mobile whether I want to allow webcam access. I can also see on the console that the webcam is delivering frames and there is also a statement there how many frames have been processed. I also followed this advice: [Flutter WebRTC camera doesn't show up](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69026441/flutter-webrtc-camera-doesnt-show-up/)

## Update 29.01.24

It turned out that once flutter is running ('flutter run') pressing 'r' to reload the app, shows the video! But its still unclear why it doesn't work at startup.

This is the content of my `main.dart` file:

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_webrtc/flutter_webrtc.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter WebRTC Demo Title',
      theme: ThemeData(
        colorScheme: ColorScheme.fromSeed(seedColor: Colors.deepPurple),
        useMaterial3: true,
      ),
      home: const MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter WebRTC Test'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyHomePage({super.key, required this.title});
  final String title;

  @override
  State<MyHomePage> createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  final _localRenderer = RTCVideoRenderer();

  @override
  dispose() async {
    await _localRenderer.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    _initRenderers();
    _getUserMedia();
    setState(() {});
    super.initState();
  }

  _initRenderers() async {
    await _localRenderer.initialize();
  }

  _getUserMedia() async {
    final Map<String, dynamic> mediaConstraints = {
      'audio': true,
      'video': true,
    };
    MediaStream stream =
        await navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia(mediaConstraints);
    _localRenderer.srcObject = stream;
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        backgroundColor: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.inversePrimary,
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: RTCVideoView(_localRenderer)
    );
  }
}
```